# EVPN VxLAN arp suppression TCAM carving

Tags: cisco, network, cisco-nexus, vxlan, evpn

Deploying Clos design network using leaf Cisco Nexus 9396PX and when trying to configure arp-suppression using tcam carving getting this error

Free up tcam slice from VACL (default vacl tcam is 512)

```
# hardware access-list tcam region vacl 0
```

Giving it to arp-ether but throwing error.

```
# hardware access-list tcam region arp-ether 256 double-wide
ERROR: Aggregate TCAM region configuration exceeded the available Ingress TCAM slices. Please re-configure.
```

If i remove `double-wide` then its not throwing error, now question is do i need double-wide and what is the use of double-wide tcam for arp-ether?

Comment: double-wide doubles the allocation to be 512 (256 x 2) instead of 256. Clearly you only have < 512 available in the TCAM.

Comment: VACL has 512 which i free up and make it zero `0` and now i want to use that 512 for double-wide arp-ether. why double-wide throwing error but not single wide

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when I configure non double-wide `arp-ether` region the following warning pops up which is quite self-explanatory with the conclusion being -- we have to use double-wide for VxLAN.

> WARNING: Configuring  the
> arp-ether region without "double-wide" is deprecated and can result in
> silent non-vxlan packet drops. Use the "double-wide" keyword when
> carving TCAM space for the arp-ether region.

Reading this document from Cisco (https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/nexus-9000-series-switches/119032-nexus9k-tcam-00.html) which you probably already saw I draw the following conclusions:

`vacl` that you try to use to free up 512 entries is actually a single "slice" and "double-wide" needs two slices of 256 or 512, so you have to reconsider the way to allocate the regions...

> This error occurs when you try to configure a **valid** amount of TCAM
> space **with regards to the 4k limit**, but your allocation consumes **more**
> **slices** **than** are **available**.  The only solution for this error is to
> revisit your intended TCAM carving design in order to free up slices.
> This error is more common when you try to configure a new double-width
> feature, as they require at least two slices of 256 or 512.

Comment: what will go wrong if i use `hardware access-list tcam region arp-ether 256` without double-wide? am i going to loose some feature or just matter of space?

Comment: @Satish as per warning I've added: "Configuring the arp-ether region without "double-wide" is deprecated and *can result in silent non-vxlan packet drops*" -- I can not add anything on top of that, but considering it's coming from the Cisco switch itself I would not go with such config